# Grand Marquis Tune Up

Tags: mercury, grand-marquis, tune-up

Just recently received a 1995 Grand Marquis from my kids. I just need to know what items I need to do a full tune up on this vehicle.

Comment: Presumably it is completely standard fitment with Modular V8, so it will have fuel injection and electronic ignition?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need at least the following:

- Spark plug wires
- Spark plugs
- O2 sensors (2ea pre-cat; 2ea post-cat)

You'll also want to clean the Mass Air Flow (MAF) sensor using MAF cleaner. Be careful with it as it is sensitive.

If the oil hasn't been changed recently, you'll want to do this as well. Oil contaminated with fuel can cause issues with your engine running optimally.

You'll probably want to run a can or two of fuel injector cleaner through the gas tank to ensure the injectors are working correctly. You'd want to use a product like SeaFoam or BG 44K. There are others on the market, though this type works better than the small bottles of STP or store branded stuff from Autozone/Advance.

Comment: Wouldn’t this be classed as more of a service than a tune-up.  Do you think that is what the OP was talking about?  I was going to suggest things like a strobe lamp and an exhaust analyser.  Maybe I jumped to the wrong conclusion 